# Android + Arduino Bluetooth seekbar control Servo

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, seekbar

I'm trying to control a servo with an android phone and an arduino via bluetooth. ,Everything is working But when I use seekbar ,program shout down.

Direction buttons working data send to ardunio and I can operate the servos . I have a problem data transfer with seekbar.

```
package com.example.androidremote;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class AndroidRemoteActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private TextView logview, textviiv;
    private Button connect, deconnect;
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    OutputStream outstream;
    private ImageView forwardArrow, backArrow, rightArrow, leftArrow, stop;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;

    private String[] logArray = null;

    private BtInterface bt = null;

    static final String TAG = "Chihuahua";
    static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;

    //This handler listens to messages from the bluetooth interface and adds them to the log
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String data = msg.getData().getString("receivedData");
            addToLog(data);            
        }
    };

    //this handler is dedicated to the status of the bluetooth connection
    final Handler handlerStatus = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            int status = msg.arg1;
            if(status == BtInterface.CONNECTED) {
                addToLog("Connected");
            } else if(status == BtInterface.DISCONNECTED) {
                addToLog("Disconnected");
            }
        }
    };

    //handles the log view modification
    //only the most recent messages are shown
    private void addToLog(String message){
        for (int i = 1; i < logArray.length; i++){
            logArray[i-1] = logArray[i];
        }
        logArray[logArray.length - 1] = message;

        logview.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < logArray.length; i++){
            if (logArray[i] != null){
                logview.append(logArray[i] + "\n");
            }
        }       
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_remote);

        //first, inflate all layout objects, and set click listeners

        logview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.logview);
        textviiv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //I chose to display only the last 3 messages
        logArray = new String[3];

        connect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        connect.setOnClickListener(this);

        deconnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.deconnect);
        deconnect.setOnClickListener(this);

        forwardArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.forward_arrow);
        forwardArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        backArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.back_arrow);
        backArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        rightArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.right_arrow);
        rightArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        leftArrow = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.left_arrow);
        leftArrow.setOnClickListener(this);
        stop = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);

        seekbar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);


        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            int progress=0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progress=progressValue;
                try{
                    outstream.write(progress);
                    textviiv.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                }
                catch(IOException e){

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });
    }

    //it is better to handle bluetooth connection in onResume (ie able to reset when changing screens)
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //first of all, we check if there is bluetooth on the phone
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            Log.v(TAG, "Device does not support Bluetooth");
        }
        else{
            //Device supports BT
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                //if Bluetooth not activated, then request it 
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
            else{
                //BT activated, then initiate the BtInterface object to handle all BT communication
                bt = new BtInterface(handlerStatus, handler);
            }
        }
    }

    //called only if the BT is not already activated, in order to activate it
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent moreData){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                //BT activated, then initiate the BtInterface object to handle all BT communication
                bt = new BtInterface(handlerStatus, handler);
            }
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
                Log.v(TAG, "BT not activated");
            else
                Log.v(TAG, "result code not known");
        }
        else{
            Log.v(TAG, "request code not known");       
        }
     }

    //handles the clicks on various parts of the screen
    //all buttons launch a function from the BtInterface object
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == connect) {
            addToLog("Trying to connect");
            bt.connect();           
        } 
        else if(v == deconnect) {
            addToLog("closing connection");
            bt.close();         
        }
        else if(v == forwardArrow) {
            //addToLog("Move Forward");
            bt.sendData("F");
        }
        else if(v == backArrow) {
            //addToLog("Move back");
            bt.sendData("B");
        }
        else if(v == rightArrow) {
            //addToLog("Turn Right");
            bt.sendData("R");
        }
        else if(v == leftArrow) {
            //addToLog("Turn left");
            bt.sendData("L");
        }
        else if(v == stop) {
            //addToLog("Stopping");
            bt.sendData("S");
        }

        /*else if(v == seekbar) {
            //addToLog("Stopping");
            bt.sendData("progress");
        }*/
    }
}
```

What can I do? I am making an error but I can't find it.

Comment: Help us help you by posting a stack trace.

Comment: I have edited your post to remove the code snippet. Code snippets are only for Javascript, HTML and CSS. If you have any other code, please just indent it with four spaces.